Dynamically change Kafka binder without application restart for consumer
We are having two Kafka clusters in two region as active passive mode. During active cluster failure, the consumer binding need to change to passive cluster without restart. We are using spring cloud stream and function. Kindly suggest
I tried unbind and setdefault binder and bindconsumer but the offset fetch not happening
